# How pass all values of a form controls to another form when checkbox is selected?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material

I got in form #1: Input and select. and in the form #2 the same fields and the checkbox. How pass the values of the form #1 to the form #2 when i clicked the checkbox?

HTML code:

```
<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput placeholder="Nombre" formControlName="names" required>
  <mat-error *ngIf= "f?.names?.errors?.required"> 
    Name field empty or not valid, please check 
  </mat-error>
</mat-form-field>

<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>Provincia </mat-label>
  <mat-select formControlName="province" required>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let p of provincies" [value]=p?.locationCode>{{p.locationName}}</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

Checkbox on form #2:

```
<mat-checkbox>Same info?</mat-checkbox>
```

Comment: Can you provide some sample code?

Comment: you can use `document.forms` and it will return you an array with all the forms in the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do this generically without concern for whether the forms are identical or how many controls there may be or if there are nested form groups or form arrays, you can copy values based on common control names and use recursion:

HTML

```
<form [formGroup]="form1">...</form>

<form [formGroup]="form2">
  <mat-checkbox (change)="$event.checked ? copyValues(form1, form2) : {}">Copy</mat-checkbox>
  ...
</form>
```

TS

```
form1: FormGroup;
form2: FormGroup;
...
copyValues(src: FormGroup, dest: FormGroup) {
  Object.keys(src.controls).forEach((key: string) => {
    const destControl = dest.get(key);
    if (destControl) {
      if (destControl instanceof FormGroup || destControl instanceof FormArray) {
        this.copyValues(src.get(key), destControl);
      } else {
        destControl.setValue(src.get(key).value);
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Note that I didn't implement any handling for an un-check action - whether to clear the form or do something else is up to you.

Comment: Thanks too much! that's work for me. Muchas Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of ways to do this.

One method is to use service.

Make an angular service and make get and set function like this

```
 // declare global variable in service
data : any;

 // function to set form-1 data
public setFormData(formData){
  this.data = formData;
}

// function to get form-1 data
public getFormData(){
  return this.data;
}
```

In your form-1 component call `setFormData` function on formSubmit like this

```
onSubmit(){
   this.myService.setFormData(this.MyForm.value);
}
```

And in your form-2 component call `getFormData` in `ngOnInit`

```
ngOnInit(){
    this.form1Data = this.myService.getFormData();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First add template variables to your inputs in first form:

```
<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput placeholder="Nombre" formControlName="names" required #nameVar>
  <mat-error *ngIf= "f?.names?.errors?.required"> 
    Name field empty or not valid, please check 
  </mat-error>
</mat-form-field>

<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>Provincia </mat-label>
  <mat-select formControlName="province" required>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let p of provincies" [value]=p?.locationCode>{{p.locationName}} #optionVar></mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

Then you can make some function on change value in checkbox and pass values, for example:

```
<mat-checkbox (change)="test($event, nameVar.value, optionVar.value)">Same info?</mat-checkbox>
```

then in controller fetch your values, for example in your controller:

```
test(event, name, option) {
    console.log(event.checked, name, option);
}
```